# insert table function how to get the values in

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, html-table

I made this insert table row function. I need to get the values of p_iId, d_prijs, c_prijs, code, artikelNL into the table. How can I do this?

```
function insertTableRow ( p_iId, d_prijs, c_prijs, code, artikelNL )
{
    var $id = $('.buttonbewerken[data-id='+p_iId+']');
    var row = '<tr>';
    row += '<td class="d_prijs ruimte">5427.00</td>';
    row += '<td class="c_prijs ruimte">9999.99</td>';
    row += '<td class="code ruimte">45t45tdfgr</td>';
    row += '<td class="artikelnl ruimte">gdrge5t5</td>';
    row += '<td><button data-id= class="buttonbewerken">bewerken</button></td>';
    row += '</tr>';

    $('#result').prepend(row);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply replace them in your string :

```
 function insertTableRow ( p_iId, d_prijs, c_prijs, code, artikelNL )
 {
    var $id = $('.buttonbewerken[data-id='+p_iId+']');
    var row = '<tr>';
    row += '<td class="d_prijs ruimte">'+d_prijs+'</td>';
    row += '<td class="c_prijs ruimte">'+c_prijs+'</td>';
    row += '<td class="code ruimte">'+code+'</td>';
    row += '<td class="artikelnl ruimte">'+artikelNL+'</td>';
    row += '<td><button data-id="'+p_iId+'" class="buttonbewerken">bewerken</button></td>';
    row += '</tr>';

    $('#result').prepend(row);
}
```

Comment: And where can i get the id than? I need to get the id where data id=

Comment: What do you mean? Your id is your function first parameter.

Comment: I need to get the id on buttonbewerken so i can update it after i inserted it

Comment: Oh, I edited my answer.

Comment: hmm data id becomes [object Object]

Comment: got it! finally did it with data-id='+p_iId+' thx for the help!

Comment: You don't really use your `$id` var. So I simply put `p_iId` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, if you can use EcmaScript 6

```
function insertTableRow ( p_iId, d_prijs, c_prijs, code, artikelNL )
{
 var $id = $('.buttonbewerken[data-id='+p_iId+']');
 var row = '<tr>';
 row += `<td class="d_prijs ruimte">${p_iId}</td>;
  <td class="c_prijs ruimte">${d_prijs}</td>
  <td class="code ruimte">${c_prijstd}>
  <td class="artikelnl ruimte"${code}></td>
  <td><button data-id=${p_iId} class="buttonbewerken">bewerken</button></td>
  </tr>`;

 $('#result').prepend(row);
}
```

Comment: If you use String templates, at least get rid of all those `+=`, since it's useless with `

Comment: Yeah, much better, i edit